# Find the largest number with unique digits, that is divisible by each of its digits

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle, no-computers, optimization

Find the largest number with unique digits, that is divisible by each of its digits.

For example 132 has unique digits and is divisible by 1, 2 and 3. But it is not the largest such number. Can you find the largest without a computer, using pen, paper and some thinking only?